# Named aggregations with pandas group by agg are super slow. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a df with many groups.

```
N = int(1E6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(300_000, size=N),
                  'B': np.random.rand(N)})
df.loc[::2, ['B']] = np.nan
```

I want to calculate the sum of each group, given that the group has at least one non-Nan value.
I encounter that the following is very slow:

```
df.groupby('A').agg(**{
  'newname' : ('B', lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1))
})
```

(22 seconds)

while the following is fast:

```
df.groupby('A').sum(min_count=1)
```

(0.11 seconds).

However I would like to use named aggregations.

Am I doing something wrong in the named_aggregation approach, hereby reducing performance?
I tried functools.partial as well (instead of the lambda function), but this yields the same performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you pass in `lambda`, the operation is no longer vectorized *across the groups* even though it can be vectorized *within each group*. For example:
`df.groupby('A').agg(**{'newname' : ('B', 'sum')})` is comparable to `df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()` and is largely faster than `lambda x: x.sum()`.

That said, I read somewhere that named agg can be a bit slower than straight up applying the built-in functions. For example, this would be a bit faster than `.agg`:

```
d = df.groupby('A')

pd.DataFrame({'new_name': d['B'].sum(min_count=1), 
              'other_name': d['B'].size()
            })
```

but then, you code base looks not as clean as `.agg`.

Comment: Well its a shame that there is not a real clean solution. Thanks however for the explanation and the example.

Answer (score 1):

One reason the second solution is faster could be because internally, it's using [Cython](https://cython.org/), which is Python converted to C, and is known to be much faster for algorithms.

[`GroupBy.sum()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb839779749a2cd71cbb8968282fff55f430ad6b/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2030-L2046) [calls](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb839779749a2cd71cbb8968282fff55f430ad6b/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2039-L2044) [`GroupBy._agg_general()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb839779749a2cd71cbb8968282fff55f430ad6b/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1448-L1465), which in turn [calls](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb839779749a2cd71cbb8968282fff55f430ad6b/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1459-L1464) [`GroupBy._cython_agg_general()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb839779749a2cd71cbb8968282fff55f430ad6b/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1459-L1464)...